# A question about effective smooth action

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, fiber-bundles

Let $G$ be a Lie group acting smooth and effectively in a manifold $S$. Let $M$ be another manifold and $f:M \longrightarrow G$ a function such that the function:
$$ F:M\times S \longrightarrow S$$
$$ F(x,s)=f(x)\cdot s$$
Is smooth.

Can we deduce that $f:M \longrightarrow G$ is smooth?

PS: for free actions or actions with a trivial isotropy group in some point $s\in S$ It's true. Because we have the diffeomorphism:
$$ H: G \longrightarrow G\cdot s $$
$$ H(g)=g\cdot s$$
And recover locally $f$ by the smooth map:
$$ x \mapsto H^{-1}\circ F(x,s)=f(x) $$

Is this argument generalizable to the general case?

Comment: Your map $H^{-1}$ in general is not even continuous. Are you assuming that the action is proper?

Comment: I'm not assuming it. The map $H:G \longrightarrow S$, $H(g)=g \cdot s$ has constant rank because is $G$-equivariant. If the isotropy group $G_s$ is trivial, then $H$ is injective so and injective immersion with image $G\cdot s$.

Comment: Yes, but it not be a homeomorphism to its image: Think of a dense subgroup of $S^1\times S^1$ isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$.